# fork call not executing child code

Tags: c, fork

Here is my updated code snippet

```
for (int i=0; i<30; i++){

        printf("Forking\n");

        tmpPid = fork();

        switch(tmpPid)

       {
         case -1:

            printf("Error");
            break;
         case 0:

          printf("Fork success for proc %d\n", i);
          //call some function
           _exit(0)
           break;

         default:

         printf("Fork succeed");
         //store the pid in a vector
          break;
    }
}

//iterate through the vector and wait on each process.
// waitpid(vectorList[i], &exitStatus, WNOHANG)
```

Forking of almost 15-18 child process works fine. But for some process, the child code is not executed at all and the child process just hangs. (i,e fork() only returns child id but not zero). 
If i buy more time inside the for loop by calling some other dummy functions, then this problem is not seen.
Can anyone tell me whats the problem ? Is it necessary to put delay between multiple forks ?

Thanks

Comment: The bug is in code not shown, most likely the function you call in `case 0` (for example, if it doesn't call `_exit`, that's probably your problem). Give us a complete, compilable, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: If the code in `some function` ever returns, isn't this pretty much a [fork bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb)?

Comment: I forgot to mention _exit(0) here. It is there in my actual code. Still 1 or 2 process never hit the child code but the parent is executed.

Comment: You should provide an output highlighting where you think things are going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure the program does what it was initially intended to do.

Basically

```
  for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
      print("Forking\n");
      fork();
  }
```

reasoning from the end having `N == 30`.

- for i == 29: the *child* and *parent* end the *for* loop and die
- for i == 28: the *parent* has still to do *29*, and so does the *child*...

etc...

Instead of 30 "Forking" displayed, there will be `2^0+2^1+2^2+...+2^29` "Forking"s.

I.e. `2^N-1` or `2^30 - 1`, or `1,073,741,823` forkings.

It is likely that the system complains and hangs reaching either a ulimit / system / window / user / shell limit depending on your OS.

Maybe

```
  for (i=0 ; i<N ; i++) {
      print("Forking\n");
      if (fork()) exit(0);
  }
```

or in the snippet have `default:` to `exit(0);` making the *children* die (horrible words) would provide the intended result.

Answer (score 1):

If the parent process is killed, then child also will be get killed. So we need to inform the parent process to wait till child finishes its work. Use `wait` or `waitpid` in your program.

`wait` will block the calling process until any one of its child process terminates.

`waitpid` will block the calling process until the child process which mentioned in first agrument terminates.

Answer (score 0):

Some child processes may not have time to print before the parent dies.

You need to `wait` for the child processes before ending the parent process.

There could also be the problem of several child processes writing to the same output stream simultaneously. (Can anyone verify that this is a potential problem?)

Comment: However, in the childs part, i am calling a function which is not getting executed. (As i have mentioned, this behavior is not seen for all the child process. Only 1 or 2 process just hangs)

Comment: In that case it would depend on what the function is doing. There is no constraint on how often `fork()` can be called.